# What is the way in ASP.NET Core 3.0 to get current authenticated User username?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm working on the latest ASP.NET Core 3.0 Angular template. What I need to know is how we can get authenticated user, username in `ActionFilterAttribute`.

The `ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` returns the current user id, and `ClaimTypes.Name` returns the username which is null.

Here is my code:

[image]

where `getUser` has a `UserId` of `d15f997a-6f65-4eb2-aecb-8b525361ae50`

I've also register IHttpContextAccessor in the Startup class as follows:

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        //Database Setup
        services.AddDbContext<HashooDBContext>(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        return ContainerSetup.InitializeWeb(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), services);
}
```

Controller.cs:

```
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/{companycode}")]
public class DashboardTransactionsController : ControllerBase
{
    [CustomAuthorizationFilter("companycode")]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Welcome";
    }
}
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this issue, it is caused by that the `IdentityServer4` did not add the `JwtClaimTypes.Name` to the access_token. If you check the access_token from web brower, you will find it miss `"name": "Tom",` node.

For a workaround, you could implement your own `ITokenService` like

```
public class CustomTokenService : DefaultTokenService
{
    public CustomTokenService(IClaimsService claimsProvider
        , IReferenceTokenStore referenceTokenStore
        , ITokenCreationService creationService
        , IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor
        , ISystemClock clock
        , IKeyMaterialService keyMaterialService
        , ILogger<DefaultTokenService> logger) 
        : base(claimsProvider, referenceTokenStore, creationService, contextAccessor, clock, keyMaterialService, logger)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<Token> CreateAccessTokenAsync(TokenCreationRequest request)
    {

        Logger.LogTrace("Creating access token");
        request.Validate();

        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.AddRange(await ClaimsProvider.GetAccessTokenClaimsAsync(
            request.Subject,
            request.Resources,
            request.ValidatedRequest));

        if (request.ValidatedRequest.Client.IncludeJwtId)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.JwtId, CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(16)));
        }
        claims.Add(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, request.Subject.GetDisplayName()));
        var issuer = Context.HttpContext.GetIdentityServerIssuerUri();
        var token = new Token(OidcConstants.TokenTypes.AccessToken)
        {
            CreationTime = Clock.UtcNow.UtcDateTime,
            Issuer = issuer,
            Lifetime = request.ValidatedRequest.AccessTokenLifetime,
            Claims = claims.Distinct(new ClaimComparer()).ToList(),
            ClientId = request.ValidatedRequest.Client.ClientId,
            AccessTokenType = request.ValidatedRequest.AccessTokenType
        };

        foreach (var api in request.Resources.ApiResources)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(api.Name))
            {
                token.Audiences.Add(api.Name);
            }
        }

        return token;
    }
}
```

And then register `CustomTokenService` before Identity Configuration

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddTransient<ITokenService, CustomTokenService>();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    }
```

For a simple way, you could try to override `DefaultClaimsService.GetStandardSubjectClaims` like

```
public class CustomClaimsService : DefaultClaimsService
{
    public CustomClaimsService(IProfileService profile
        , ILogger<DefaultClaimsService> logger) : base(profile, logger)
    {
    }
    protected override IEnumerable<Claim> GetStandardSubjectClaims(ClaimsPrincipal subject)
    {
        var claims = base.GetStandardSubjectClaims(subject);
        var newClaims = new List<Claim>(claims)
        {
            new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Name, subject.Identity.Name)
        };
        return newClaims;
    }
}
```

And register like

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.TryAddTransient<IClaimsService, CustomClaimsService>();

        //services.TryAddTransient<ITokenService, CustomTokenService>();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

    }
```

Comment: I'm using the CustomTokenService class and all works perfectly except that I do not get the User.Identity.Name on DELETE verbs, any idea why not? Or is this more an angular problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use IHttpContextAccessor

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

public UserService(
    IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
  _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;       
}
```

And to get user name you can use

```
_httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;
```

Or

```
 _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Then register in your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
}
```

Comment: I'm using ActionExecutingContext as a parameter. You want me to replace it with IHttpContextAccessor?

Comment: @AhmerAliAhsan IHttpContextAccessor should be accessable from any service class within same assemblie. So yes try ahead to see if it work for you

Comment: can you adjust it with my code? `public CustomAuthorizationFilter(string companyCode)
        {
            _companyCode = companyCode;
        }`

Comment: There's no reason to do this. The `ActionExecutingContext.HttpContext` property already gives access to the `HttpContext` instance.

Comment: @KirkLarkin yes you're right but `context.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name;` this code show me null value

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
string userId = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
```

Comment: [Please don't post “try this code” as an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256359/).

Comment: He should not post "try this code", you're right.
But this fixed my problem. +1